# xCode 6.1.1 slow and keeps freezing

Tags: xcode, indexing, freeze

I'm having some trouble working with xCode. It just keeps hanging and using 100% CPU right after a couple lines of code. I'm working on a new project and it barely has two files and it has become completely imposible to work with.
I tried reinstalling xCode and starting my project from scratch but it won't work.

I noticed three things that may help someone find out what it's going on.

1. It's slow even when typing, the characters appear delayed on the screen.
2. It keeps saying indexing on the task bar on top. If I clean the project it will disappear but come back whenever I start working again.
3. It overheats as soon as I open xCode

And here's some other facts that might help

1. I'm running xCode 6.1.1 (build 6A2008a)
2. My Mac is a mid 2012 MacBook pro 8GB Ram
3. I did a fresh install of Yosemite a month after it was released, so it's pretty clean.
4. I'm using the latest build of Xampp for my SQL server
5. I'm using nodejs as a backend so I'm running an http with nodemon

Hope any of you has a solution to this.

Thanks and merry christmas to all of you.

**EDIT**

I found out that it will build just fine if I remove my conditional cast to NSInteger, NSString, Float, etc. I have like 8 of them one after the other, and just replacing `as?` for `as` did the trick. I'm curious as for why this is happening anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problems on 6.1.1 (but also source kit crashes) were improved (but not completely resolved) for me by deleting derived data.